# How to Fix Broken Visual Studios and SQL Server Management Studios after Win10 Upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, windows-10-desktop

**Background**

Our group just upgraded Win7 to Win10 for all Windows PCs. After the upgrade, all existing visual studios (2005/2008/2010/2012/2013/2015) and SSMS (2008/2012/2014) became broken. When any of them was run, it threw an error of infamous "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". Microsoft suggested simple re-installations of VS/SSMS for this problem, but I found on Web that this reinstallation may get you into more trouble.

At this point, I am badly tempted to clean-install Windows 10 to the machine and then reinstall VS/SSMS, but the machine has about 810 other software packages which may be hard to be reinstalled to the new OS.

**Question**

is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: When you say you don't want to reinstall, do you include the "Repair" option?

Comment: @GSerg If you meant repair by installation repair of the packages, I have tried several times with my test machine and found it never worked. I found my solution. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix to this problem.

1. Install .NET 4.6.2
2. Reboot
3. type following two statements in admin command prompt

> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
>
> sfc /scannow

4. Reboot
5. Now you should see all VS/SSMS are working gain.

In the statements above, **D:** drive is of Windows 10 DVD.